# Wordpress Auto Draft disabling

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress v.3.3.1 With Multisite management on.

I am trying to disable the auto draft function, but it seems that I have tried everythig.

What I have tried:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);

define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);
```

Didn't work.

I have tried to remove the auto_save lines in post-new.php, post-php. Both in wp-includes and in wp-admin. Didn't work.

I have also tried several plugins, but they won't do it! Any idea why?

Answer (score 31):

I notice that you are asking about disabling **Auto-Drafts** and NOT **Auto-Save**.

You cannot disable Auto-save, but you can achieve a similar affect by setting a long interval, for example:

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 3600 ); // Default is 60
```

*(You'd add it in your WordPress site's wp-config.php file.)*

As for Auto-Drafts, you don't want to disable them. They are there for an important reason. Let me grab a quote or two for ya...

Samuel 'Otto' Wood, Tech Ninja at Audrey Capital (Matt Mullenweg's angel investment company), [says](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Disable-Stop-auto-draft-posts-tp914p917.html):

> Auto-drafts exist because of the fact that multiple users can create new posts at the same time. If two people enter post-new at roughly the same moment, then have their first autosaves occur nearly simultaneously, then there is a race condition that can cause one of them to get back the wrong post ID, which will cause a post to be overwritten/lost when they then continue editing the post.
>
> The auto-draft creates the post and gets the ID of the new post before the editing screen is displayed, thus preventing two simultaneous authors from accidentally having the same post ID in the data in their browser.

Andrew Ozz, who worked on WordPress' TinyMCE integration, [says](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Disable-Stop-auto-draft-posts-tp914p924.html):

> This also makes it possible to upload images before the first draft is saved and they will be properly attached to the new post.

[And lastly](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Disable-Stop-auto-draft-posts-tp914p923.html):

> Auto-drafts are automatically deleted after 7 days of going unused. They're self-cleaning, basically. No need to worry about them.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks for brining in this info!

Comment: Finally, a clear answer about what happens to unused auto-drafts -- they get deleted after 7 days. I've been looking for this. Thanks!

Comment: For the users with Gutenberg Editor, please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234271/wordpress-auto-draft-disabling/65420515#65420515) to disable auto-saving feature.

Answer (score 6):

A) Set it in your wp-config.php file. Else it won't work.

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL',    3600 );     // autosave 1x per hour
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS',    false );    // no revisions
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON',      true );
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS',     7 );        // one week
```

Comment: You sure this disables auto-DRAFTS from being created?

Comment: @its_me Set it to a near to infinite amount of time.

Comment: But that only disables auto-SAVE. An auto-DRAFT is created (almost) right when the "Add New" post link is clicked. You see what I mean?

Comment: @its_me yes, I misread that. Didn't notice it as the OP didn't care to comment or make any other process. That's why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @its_me That auto-draft is your "original" post. WordPress else does **not** know where to save data, hence the "intermediate" set of data. What you read as "auto-draft" is just the post title as there would be none when you click "Add New Post". WP has an initial save happening per design to have a dataset to add to.

Comment: So i am creating a plugin. How do i implement this functionality inside it ?

Answer (score 1):

Open wp-config.php located in your WordPress root directory and add following code:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );
```

before of `require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';` or and top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

For guys who use WordPress 5.0+ version with Gutenberg Editor, the below code snippet works to disable auto drafting/saving

```
/**
 * Disables auto saving feature for Gutenberg Editor (set interval by 3600s)
 */
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings', 'rsm0128_block_editor_settings', 10, 2 );
function rsm0128_block_editor_settings( $editor_settings, $post ) {
    $editor_settings['autosaveInterval'] = 3600;
    return $editor_settings;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think **disabling it is not good** (for example, when you parallely try to publish 2 posts, then there may be problems).  So, instead, **of disabling**:

## Method 1)

- disable them slightly (without CORE-modifications), see [**this answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216447/33667).

## Method 2)

- just clean them using [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw/kveXGqJT) or good plugin [WP Clean Up](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clean-up/)