# Disable creating “Post ID”, if page “post-new.php” is empty in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

The permalink structure of my website is **"/%post_id%/"** (website.com/123/).

I've disabled revisions and autosave for posts.

But how to disable auto-creating "Post ID", when I open "website.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" even if I don't entered anything in editor? If I press "F5" a few times, the number of "Post ID" will increase accordingly.

How to fix it?
Thank's for your help!

Comment: I don't think this can be "fixed" as that's how the WordPress editor works: WordPress does this so the user can use the Preview Post/Page functionality (and surely for other stuff as well). Leaving the screen without making changes will discard the post/page and its assigned ID as well. The next post/page will get a higher ID because the ID field is an [autoincremental](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) one. I'm curious what other might say though so I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: Found out that it's about Auto-Draft, which can't be changed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234271/wordpress-auto-draft-disabling/19546879#19546879

Comment: Yep, that too. WP uses the autodraft for a few things: previews, revisions, etc, and as you said can't be disabled because it's a core functionality.